# How to create a hide and show FAQ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing a FAQ page for my website and currently I am stuck in a place. I want to create a page such that on clicking the question the answer is shown and on clicking another question should open and the previous answer should hide automatically. to some far I was successful in doing it, I could open a new question and the previous question was hiding and the new questions answer was shown. But if i go and click on the previous question again it didn't open.

here is the code that I had written

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {

     $("#container li").click(function() {

       $("#container p").slideUp();
       var text = $(this).children('div.panel');

       if (text.is(':hidden')) {
         text.slideDown('200');
         $(this).children('span').html('-');
       } else {
         text.slideUp('200');
         $(this).children('span').html('+');
       }

     })

   });
```

```css
   #container {
     list-style: none;
     font-family: arial;
     font-size: 20px;
   }
   #container li {
     margin: 10px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
     position: relative;
     cursor: pointer;
   }
   #container h3 {
     margin: 0;
     font-size: 24px;
   }
   #container span {
     position: absolute;
     right: 5px;
     top: 0;
     color: #000;
     font-size: 18px;
   }
   #container .panel {
     margin: 5px 0;
     display: none;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="container">
  <li>
    <h3>this is first</h3>
    <span>+</span>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>this is second</h3>
    <span>+</span>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>helelo</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>this is third</h3>
    <span>+</span>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>how are you</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There's a widget for that: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) and [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) for this:

```
$("#container li").click(function(){
    $(this).find('div').slideToggle();
    $(this).children('span').html('-');
    $("#container li").not(this).find('div').slideUp();
    $("#container li").not(this).children('span').html('+');
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crenfpo0/1/)

Comment: thanks, but i want even the **+** sign to change. That is when the answer is shown i want it to become **-**, similar to what i had done.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery's [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), along with the [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) method to refactor your jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container li").click(function() {
    $('#container li div').slideUp();
    $('#container li span').text('+');
    $(this).find('.panel').slideToggle();
    $(this).find('span').text('-');
  });
});
```

---

## Live Demo:

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container li").click(function() {
    $('#container li div').slideUp();
    $('#container li span').text('+');
    $(this).find('.panel').slideToggle();
    $(this).find('span').text('-');
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#container li {
  margin: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#container h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#container span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#container .panel {
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <ul id="container">
    <li>
      <h3>this is first</h3>
      <span>+</span>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>this is second</h3>
      <span>+</span>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>helelo</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>this is third</h3>
      <span>+</span>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>how are you</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>


</body>
```

Comment: This does not satisfy the needs of the OP. She needs to be able to hide the question that is open when clicking a new question - "I could open a new question and the previous question was hiding".

Comment: @97ldave: Sorry, fixed

Comment: Your function is firing twice when you click on a heading that is already open. Other than that everything seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use one of the millions of accordions plugins out there, instead of reinventing the wheel?  Like [jQueryUI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). Here are [10 others](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-great-accordions/).
Hope it helps :)